# How to get the unique count number of multi field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I know single field.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "uniq_attr": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "name.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know a clumsy approach

```js
{
    "aggs" : {
        "multi_field_cardinality" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "script": "doc['name.keyword'].value + ' _my_custom_separator_ ' + doc['id_number.keyword'].value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BUT 
I want to know by 'field' rather than 'script'